# RecyclerView item with custom layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make a view with first item is larger than others like [attach image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbKpQ.png). i used RecyclerView but i don't know how to custom layout for first item. Someone please tell me the way to do it.

Many thanks!

Comment: This tutorial might help you get started: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into **view types** for `RecyclerView`. This allows you to use different layouts for different types of rows. You can find several examples on this site [such as this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a StaggeredGridLayout in your RecyclerView. It will look like Pinterest and you can then put all the items of the same size, except for the first one where you can put a bigger one and the layout will do everything for you. The StaggeredGridLayout will look like this:
[image: StaggeredGridLayout]

You can also use a GridLayout and make an item use more than one cell like here:
[image: GridLayout]

You can easily google for a tutorial using the terms I provided.

I hope it helps!